# How to setup Nginx to use ssl/non-ssl for different urls on a single site, but always use ssl if user explicity types https in browser's address bar?

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

My current `nginx.conf` looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /var/www/;
    location / {
    }
    location /users {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /var/www/;
    location /users {
    }
    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

With this configuration, the connection switches from/to ssl/non-ssl when a user navigates the pages on the site, ssl for urls started with `/users` and non-ssl for all other urls.  As a result, even the user explicitly types `https://www.example.com/` in the address bar of the browser, the resulting page is redirected to `http://www.example.com/`.

Is there a way to implement the auto-url-rewrite between ssl/non-ssl as achieved by the settings above, but still respect the explicit ssl request if `https://` is explicitly typed by user in the browser's address bar?

Comment: Why would you do that - just force ssl when desired (or simply always, site wide) and never redirect to http. And before someone says seo: canonical URL metatag.

Comment: Never tried it but couldn't you use rewrite ^ $scheme://$http_host$request_uri?

Comment: @MichaelLewis that's an infinite loop.

Comment: oh of course it would be

Answer (score 1):

From server standpoint there is no way to differ the request made by following a link, by crawling a site or by typing the full address in location bar.

When you type in an address, web browser sends HTTP request to your web server. If you typed https it will try to connect to port 443 (by default), and the request headers don't hold info if the user typed the request or the request or for example bot crawled it.

All you can do is keep SSL for certain user agents and redirect for other.